# Can JBoss be configured to auto-close JDBC connections for datasources?

Tags: jboss, jboss5.x, jboss6.x

For JAAS authentication I have configured a datasource as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<datasources>
    <local-tx-datasource>
        <jndi-name>jdbc/SomeDS</jndi-name>
        <connection-url>jdbc:path-to-server</connection-url>
        <driver-class>interbase.interclient.Driver</driver-class>
        <user-name>DBUSER</user-name>
        <password>dbpass</password>
        <min-pool-size>0</min-pool-size>
        <metadata>
            <type-mapping>Firebird</type-mapping>
        </metadata>
    </local-tx-datasource>
</datasources>
```

Unfortunately JBoss keeps the database connection open which can cause severe performance problems on our InterBase database.

As this connection is used only by the JAAS module internally, our web application has no way to force-close the connection.

Is there a way to tell JBoss to close connections after use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding `<idle-timeout-minutes>`? - It defines the maximum time a connection may be idle before being closed. Setting to 0 disables it.  Default is 15 minutes.

See http://community.jboss.org/wiki/ConfigDataSources for details.